ASP.NET MVC add and create custom session provider
I am migrating an ASP.NET MVC application (on .NET 4.8) to .NET 8. Not the idea is that the MVC stays for the time as the view layer and everything is moved to a .NET 8 REST API.
With moving to .NET Core 8, the session is moved, too. In the ASP.NET MVC application, I still need the session, because some data is retrieved from it.
Is there some common way to do this, to be able to access the ASP.NET Core state in the ASP.NET MVC application?
If not how can I register a custom state provider in the ASP.NET MVC application?

Here is official information for how to setup and use sessions in ASP.NET Core.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-8.0#configure-session-state
Here is an article from C# Corner
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-use-session-in-asp-net-core/

You missed a point. My session is in the .net core project and I need to access it in the .net framework aplication (the MVC)

Are you saying that you have two applications running independently where one app is .NET Framework MVC with session that sends requests to and another app which is .NET Core 8?

Yes, 2 app, one is .net core (API) and the session lives there now, and and the second is .net framework (MVC), and I need the session in the MVC that lives in the API

I don't think you will be able to share same sessions between two different web applications even if they both are .NET Core.  You'll probably need to implement something like "Single Sign On".
